# Giving module structure to direct sum of global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Given a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ over $X=\text{Proj}S$ for a graded ring $S$, I'd like to precisely understand how one can give $S$-module structure to the direct sum $$\underset{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\bigoplus\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}(m)).$$

More precisely looking at here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MM, I know that there is a natural map $S\to\bigoplus\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}(n))$ given by mapping $s\in S_d$ to the gluing of $\displaystyle\frac{s}{1}\in\mathcal{O}(d)(D(f))$ for an open cover made of $D(f)$'s. Moreover I also understand the construction of the morphism $\mathcal{O}(n)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}}\mathcal{O}(m)\to\mathcal{O}(n+m)$, and hence, by tensoring, of the map $\mathcal{O}(n)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}}{\mathcal{F}(m)}\to\mathcal{F}(n+m)$.

My question is: why one can say that we have a morphism $$\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigoplus\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}(n))\times\underset{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\bigoplus\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}(m))\to\underset{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\bigoplus\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}(m))?$$

This would give a $S$-module structure by what said before, but I can't understand how to find an element in $\mathcal{F}(n+m)(X)$ given $(s,t)\in\mathcal{O}(n)(X)\times\mathcal{F}(m)(X)$ using the morphism $\mathcal{O}(n)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}}{\mathcal{F}(m)}\to\mathcal{F}(n+m)$.

The main problem seems to be that for what I know it is **not** true in general that $$\mathcal{O}(n)(X)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}(X)}\mathcal{F}(m)(X)\cong(\mathcal{O}(n)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}}\mathcal{F}(m))(X),$$
otherwise I would simply consider the element $s\otimes t $. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right that in general $\mathcal{F}(X)\otimes\mathcal{G}(X)\neq(\mathcal{F\otimes G})(X)$. However, there is a natural map $\mathcal{F}(X)\otimes\mathcal{G}(X)\to(\mathcal{F\otimes G})(X)$. So what you did works, you can simply consider the image of $s\otimes t$ under that map. (Note that in general, the image is ambiguously still denoted $s\otimes t$).

Comment: Thank you for the comment :) I just want to be sure: the map you're talking about is given by universal propery of tensor product I guess, and in order to get that I need a bilinear map from cartesian product of global sections to the global sections of the tensor product. Is such a map defined on $(s,t)$ as gluing of $s|_{U}\otimes t|_{U}\in\mathcal{F}(U)\otimes\mathcal{G}(U)=(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})(U)$ for an affine open cover made of $U$'s?

Comment: It can be constructed in many ways. If you know that the tensor product of sheaves is the sheafification of $U\mapsto\mathcal{F}(U)\otimes\mathcal{G}(U)$ then this map is just the sheafification map. If you want to use the universal property of tensor product, you can indeed construct some bilinear map.